# Carrierwave-direct: Saving Image with Default Values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a Rails app where I can upload images to Amazon S3.  This is done through Carrierwave via a form with many hidden values for saving particular attributes about the image (such as the project it's associated with, etc.):

**Current Image Uploading Form**

```
  <%= semantic_form_for Image.new do |image_form| %>
    <%= image_form.input :project_id, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => @project.id} %>
    <% if @step.new_record? %>
      <%= image_form.input :step_id, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => -1} %>
      <%= image_form.input :saved, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => false} %>
    <% else %>
      <%= image_form.input :step_id, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => @step.id} %>
      <%= image_form.input :saved, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => true} %>
    <% end %>
```

I'm looking into moving the image uploading to a background task. I understand that if I use [Carrierwave-direct](https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct), then I need to have the image submitted in its own direct_upload_form, which can't pass any of the hidden values I currently have.  I also know that when the image has been successfully sent to Amazon S3, there is the **success_action_redirect** method I can call to redirect to a URL:

**New image upload form**

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.file_field :image_path %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload Image" %></p>
<% end %>
```

**New Controller method for image uploading**

```
def index
  @uploader = Image.new.image_path
  @uploader.success_action_redirect = update_image_attributes_url
end
```

What I'd like to do is have the image automatically save with all the different hidden values I had in my original form (without redirecting to a page where I would need to manually fill out a form and click submit).

The way I'm thinking of doing this is to redirect to a view with a form for editing the particular image record and automatically trigger the submit button when the page is loaded.  But I don't want the user to see a blank page when they're redirected to this page.

How can I have the success_action_redirect trigger some AJAX after the image has been uploaded to Amazon S3?  Would something like this work?

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader, :remote=> true do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.file_field :image_path %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload Image" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Or is there a better way to do this generally?